# Problem uploading images in front end joomla 4 using Jreviews component in console I see a 404 error

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, joomla4

I'm using Joomla 4 with Jreviews component, in backend it works fine, but in the front end it uses a file uploader.

The situation is, it uploads the file, but it won't get saved it the server, in console I get this

```
POST https://example.com/index.php?option=com_jreviews&format=ajax&data%5B…ile=314399505-10228753652167277-346351785741197674-n-76-1667535492+(1).jpg 404
_upload @   fileuploader.min.js?v=412:1
upload  @   fileuploader.min.js?v=412:1
_uploadFile @   fileuploader.min.js?v=412:1
_uploadFileList @   jreviews-all.min.js?v=412:5
_onInputChange  @   fileuploader.min.js?v=412:1
onChange    @   fileuploader.min.js?v=412:1
(anonymous) @   fileuploader.min.js?v=412:1
```

I'm looking if someone can give a light on this

Comment: are there any PHP error messages?

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.